# Running vba macro, got error as 'Object variable or With block variable not set'

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

Pls find the vba code I'm trying to run. I understand that I get this error. Because when I run macro1() , I'm calling a variable which is not yet initialized/declared. Is there a way to initialize public variable before procedure call.

Help me on this. If i'm wrong at my understanding, Correct me.

Note: I'm running this as Excel addins.

```
Public bugr As Variant
Public bugr_sheet As Variant
Public bugr_cell As Variant
Public scr As Variant

Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+e

'Getting current cell address
Set bugr_sheet = ActiveSheet
Set bugr_cell = ActiveCell
bugr = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & ActiveCell.Address

'Creating dummy link
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    bugr, TextToDisplay:="NA"

End Sub
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+l
'
scr = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & ActiveCell.Address
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    bugr, TextToDisplay:=bugr

    bugr_sheet.Activate
    bugr_cell.Activate
    Selection.Hyperlinks(1).SubAddress = scr
    Selection.Hyperlinks(1).TextToDisplay = scr
   End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure if you want to select a cell and make it the target to your link or if you want to make it the origin, or if you want to select 2 different cells and make it Target and Origin... In other words, could you describe what you are trying to achieve ? Thanks.

Comment: @J.Doe What I'm trying to do with that macro is - I execute macro1 I store the current cell address and the current sheets name. Now I create a hyperlink to the same cell.
Now in macro2 I create a hyperlink to the previous cell and modify the link of the previous one to redirect to my current cell.
Thereby I get a two way hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

First create a named range anywhere in your workbook called "Origin".
To do so, go to Name Manager > New... > Set the name to "Origin" and click "OK"

Once its done you can click on any cell and run this:

```
Sub Store_Cell()

ActiveWorkbook.Names("Origin").RefersToR1C1 = ActiveCell

End Sub
```

And then click on any other cell and run this:

```
Sub hyperlink()

Dim OSh As Worksheet: Set OSh = Range("Origin").Parent
Ori = OSh.Name & "!" & Range("Origin").Address
Tar = ActiveCell.Parent.Name & "!" & ActiveCell.Address
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:=Ori, TextToDisplay:="Text"
OSh.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range("Origin"), Address:="", SubAddress:=Tar, TextToDisplay:="text2"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

in Macro2 you  can check for `bugr_sheet` against being empty and, if so, setting empty variables:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+l
'
    If IsEmpty(bugr_sheet) Then
        Set bugr_sheet = Worksheets("someSheetName") 'change "someSheetName" to your actual relevant sheet name
        Set bugr_cell = bugr_sheet.Range("someRangeReference") 'change "someRangeReference" to your actual relevant sheet range address
        bugr = bugr_sheet.Name & "!" & bugr_cell.Address
    End If

    scr = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & ActiveCell.Address
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:=bugr, TextToDisplay:=bugr

    bugr_sheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=bugr_cell, Address:="", SubAddress:=scr, TextToDisplay:=scr    
End Sub
```

Comment: This again requires me to select the cell specifically... I'm trying to achieve a 2 way link without selection

Comment: the _selection_ is implicit even in your original way, since it relies on `Selection` object, so you must have the user _select_ a cell before launching your macros. Or maybe you can add more info about your exact goal

Comment: Yes mine too relies on 'Selection' object. But my objective of creating this macro is -  Hit a shortcut key(assign key mapping to macro) on your source cell once and the destination cell once and a 2 way hyperlink should be created. Because I have a lots of links to be created, so it would be better I use only keyboard and not Input box where I have to go for mouse click again.

Comment: are the two way links always linking cells in the same sheet?

Comment: then you still have to _abandon_ the keyboard and have user select the proper sheet and proper cell. otherwise you may give some more details on your actual flow

Comment: Not necessarily I have to abandon the keyboard. I could use Ctrl+PgUp/Dn to navigate between sheets. My original macro works fine & fits the purpose exactly. The only thing is I have to manually run the first 4 lines of code so that the Public variables are declared. Then the macro procedures run without an error. Could help me know - Is there any way to initialize the Global variables before the macro is called?

Comment: how would you initialize them? referencing what cell in what sheet?

Comment: It works when it is .xlsm. When I try to use it as and XL addin, it throws error. Is that any source of error?

Comment: see edited answer. don't know if XL addin could be an issue by itself

Comment: No. the edited answer might add up. But i get the error when I'm executing ' macro1()' itself.

Comment: whcih is the line in Macro1 throwing the error? and what error?

Comment: In this line - Set bugr_sheet = ActiveSheet. The error message is  'Object variable or With block variable not set'.

Comment: seems like there's no "active" sheet at the moment you run the macro. while hitting that error, click "Debug", type in Immediate Window (CTRL-G to pop it out) `?ActiveSheet.Name`, press return and see the outcome

Comment: Run-time error 483, Object doesnt support this property or this method.

Comment: try typing `?ActiveSheet is Nothing` and pressing return

Comment: ?ActiveSheet is Nothing returns false

Comment: then try typing `?Activesheet.` and see what options _intellisense_ is giving you to complete the statement after the dot: is there a `Name` option?

Comment: No after ?Activesheet., there is no auto-suggestion

Comment: try typing `?typename(activesheet)` and press return. Of course all this typing is supposed to _always_ take place right after hitting the error, having clicked "debug" and jumped to Immediate Window

Comment: Returns 'Worksheet'

Comment: and typing `?ActiveSheet.Name` and pressing return is throwing an error?

Comment: then no clues. last blind shot is `Public bugr_sheet As WorkSheet`